# How do I reset Iterm to default?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, iterm2, iterm

I accidentally installed a zshrc script from this link https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/8568070. But it completely ruined my current bash_profile and bashrc. I think it's using the zsh login shell on top of my terminal and iTerm. And now ,I have no idea on how to remove it.

I tried removing the com.company.iTerm.plist from preferences. But it still hasn't worked.

Any suggestions? I really need help.

Comment: Sorry I have an addition question here, in my .zshrc , I have `code # Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
# alias n= "nano"
# alias  m= "mkdir"
# alias w= "cd ~/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2"
# alias j= "cd ~/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2/COMP16212"`. Shouldn't it work?

Comment: i suggest that you switch to iTerm2 , as more people are familiar with.

Comment: Did you try this? defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2